# Additive Function is Continuous

Tags: analysis, proof-explanation

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. Prove/Disprove $f$ must be continuous.

Proof
 **We have $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}.$** Then, Then, we want to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow t}f(x)=f(t)$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}.$ So

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow t}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x-a+t)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)-f(a)+f(t)=f(a)-f(a)+f(t)=f(t)$$

for any $t\in\mathbb{R}.$

**I have a question that: why 
we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}.$** How do you know this? Can you explain? Thanks...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why 
>   we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}.$ How do you know this?

We don't know this, because in general it's not true.  There may not exist any such $a$.  Indeed, assuming the axiom of choice, there do exist discontinuous additive functions; see 
[Is Zorn's lemma necessary to show discontinuous $f\colon {\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}$ satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492751/is-zorns-lemma-necessary-to-show-discontinuous-f-colon-mathbb-r-to-mathb)  However, your argument does show that such a function has to be *everywhere* discontinuous; an additive function which is continuous at one point must be continuous everywhere.