# Over ZF does "every non-seperable Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis" imply "there exists a non-Lebesgue measurable set"?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

I know from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951846/over-zf-does-every-hilbert-space-have-a-basis-imply-ac) that it's an open problem whether or not the existence of a dense orthonomral basis for every real or complex Hilbert space $(\text{B}_\text{orth})$ implies the axiom of choice. This tells me that the axiom of dependent choice, $(\text{DC})$, isn't strong enough to imply that every non-seperable Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis (otherwise it wouldn't be an open problem because if $(\text{B}_\text{orth})\Rightarrow(\text{AC})$ then $(\text{DC})\Rightarrow(\text{AC})$ and the Solovay model would be unsatisfiable) so it's not immediately impossible that you can prove the existence of a non-Lebesgue measurable set, $(\text{not-LM})$, from $(\text{B}_\text{orth})$.

I know from the paper [The Hahn-Banach theorem implies the existence of a non-Lebesgue measurable set](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm138/fm13812.pdf) by Foreman and Wehrung that the full Hahn-Banach theorem is enough to prove $(\text{not-LM})$ and I know that a weakened version of the Hahn-Banach theorem for Hilbert spaces is somewhat immediate, but the proof of $(\text{not-LM})$ in that paper relies on the [equivalence of Hahn-Banach and the existence of a finitely additive measure on every Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Relation_to_axiom_of_choice) and I'm not sure how that statement is weakened for weakened versions of Hahn-Banach.

Comment: These can be difficult questions, worthy of publications in the right circumstances. One cursory search yielded no results; but the rest will have to wait for tomorrow I'm afraid.

Comment: And just to be clear, what do you mean an orthonormal basis? The span is dense or the span is everything?

Comment: I mean that the basis is dense. I'll edit the question. Are there even non-seperable Hilbert spaces with full orthonormal bases, not just dense orthonormal bases?

Comment: Well, I'm not *that* well-versed in functional analysis, or the intricacies of the terminology. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I deleted that comment because I realized I was using AC to choose a countable subset!

Comment: @Nate: But it was the principle that counts. I got the gist. That's the important part. And now I am one tiny iota closer to being prepared mentally for a six credits course in [mostly functional] analysis next year!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: But now it makes me wonder about the Hilbert space $\ell^2(A)$ where $A$ is amorphous...

Comment: @Nate: That's actually easy. Brunner has a paper about Hilbert spaces which are like that, $\ell_2(D)$ where $D$ has a Dedekind-finite power set. They have a Hamel basis which is orthonormal or something. I references this paper often on here/MO. "*Garnir's dream spaces with Hamel bases.*"

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I was reading that paper because of this question and I have a perhaps weaker question. Is it genericaly possible to use something like construction 2 (the Hilbert space over Russel's socks) to construct a choice function if you assume the space has a self-adjoint operator? I tried to read their reference [3] for this statement but the paper is far too technical for me and I can't even locate the statement that's supposed to correspond to construction 2 having no self-adjoint operators.