# Error with the proof that all solutions to the Cauchy Functional Equation are linear

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations, fake-proofs, decimal-expansion

If $f(x)$ is continuous, it is known that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ implies that $f(x)$ is linear, and non-continuous solutions are discussed in these links. ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269434/non-continuous-function-satisfies-fxy-fxfy),
[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385586/do-there-exist-functions-satisfying-fxy-fxfy-that-arent-linear),[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16175/on-sort-of-linear-functions), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487873/many-other-solutions-of-the-cauchys-functional-equation))

However, what is wrong with this proof that all solutions to the [Cauchy Functional Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) are of the form $f(x)=cx$?

If $x$ is rational, it is known that $f(x)=cx$ for some fixed constant $c$, as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144559/if-fx-y-fx-fy-showing-that-fcx-cfx-holds-for-rational-c).

If $x$ is irrational let us assume that $x=n+\alpha$, where $0 \le \alpha <1$.

$f(x)=f(n+\alpha)=f(n)+f(\alpha)$.

Because of the upper result, $f(n)=cn$.

Let the decimal expansion of $\alpha$ be $\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } }  } $

Note that $\frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } } $ is rational.

Then, $$f(\alpha)=f(\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } }  })=\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ f(\frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } } ) } =c\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } }  }=c\alpha $$

Therefore $f(x)=cn+c\alpha=cx$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: How do you prove that $f(\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } }  })$ equals $\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ f(\frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } } ) }$ without assuming $f$ continuous?

Comment: Exactly. Let $b_n=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j10^{-j}.$  Then $f(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j10^{-j})=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty}f(a_j10^{-j}) $ is equivalent to $f(\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(b_n)$.  This assumes $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the comments:

How do you prove that $f(\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ \frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } }  })$ equals $\sum _{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }{ f(\frac { { a }_{ i } }{ { 10 }^{ i } } ) }$ without assuming $f$ continuous?

Exactly. Let $b_n=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j10^{-j}$. Then $f(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j10^{-j})=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty}f(a_j10^{-j})$ is equivalent to $f(\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(b_n)$. This assumes $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$.

Comment: While this is not a question about your solution, can you explain why this is  community wiki ?

Comment: I marked it CW because the words aren't my own.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly when you are supposed to do a community wiki Q or A?

Comment: Uh, not really, I'm not an expert in such things! It's just that in this case, I didn't want to be seen as taking credit. You could try asking a question on the meta site to learn more.